# Роутер PHP. Вызов методов

Tags: php, методы, роутер

Написал роутер:

```
class App
{
private $fileOrderManager;
private $pageManager;
private $routes = [
'/' => 'getIndex',
'/admin' => 'getAdminPage',
'/order' => 'save'
];

function __construct($fileOrderManager,$pageManager)
{
$this->fileOrderManager=$fileOrderManager;
$this->pageManager= $pageManager;
}

public function run()
{
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$method = $this->routes[$path['path']] ?? 'getIndex';
if(!method_exists($this, $method)) {
   return; // throw exception
}
    $this->$method();

     $this->pageManager->getIndex();
     $this->pageManager->getAdminPage();
     $this->fileOrderManager->save();
     //$this->fileOrderManager->list();

}

}
```

Что очевидно, в таком виде оно метод не находит, срабатывает условие  method_exist и возвращает из функции. Как мне прописать, что бы вызвать методы из классов ($this->pageManager->getIndex(); и тп)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и сказанно - название методов не соответсвуют тому, что находиться в `$routes`.
Роутер, как оказалось, должен иметь метод ,который обращаеться к методам менеджеров (Менеджер ДБ, и т.д). Т.е. Метод `getIndex` у роутера должен обращаться к менеджеру страниц `pageManager` и у него вызвать соответственный метод `getIndex()`

то есть , выходом было:

```
function getIndex() {  $this->pageManager->getIndex(); }
```